# Android: Displaying a custom Dialog/PopupWindow with semi-transparent background and ability to close when focus is lost

Tags: android, dialog, transparent, popupwindow

I will start off with a bit of introduction as to what I desire my application to look like.

http://img806.imageshack.us/i/whatiwant.jpg/

I have been able to achieve that button bar and ImageView in the same layout using RelativeLayout.

Now my problem is that I want to know of a method to display that window/popup/dialog that appears after I press button 1.

What do I want with that window that spawns:
1. It should have a semi-transparent background.
2. It should close itself when focus is lost from it
3. Should have buttons and action listeners which can trigger events in the main application.

I have been looking over Android. PopupWindow but I was facing a lot of problems getting help about it i.e. It's action listeners, dismissal etc. So I dropped the idea.

For now I am working with dialogs. So far I have only been able to display a dialog. Problems
1. Custom Height and Width properties are not working for some reason (implemented using Layout Params) 
2. How to have a Semi transparent background?
3. How to dismiss/hide the dialog when the focus is lost?

My question is,are there any better ways to do this besides dialogs? If so, please tell me what they are. If using dialogs is the way to go, how should I go about solving the aforementioned problems?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PopupWindow is a better option. Check the [AutoCompleteTextView](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java;h=39714872dc7a934530b5be74639290285efd74ca;hb=HEAD) for PopupWindow example.
To create the PopupWindow use

```
PopupWindow myWindow = new PopupWindow( content_view, width, height, true )
```

Use DismissListener, if you want to do anything when popupWindow is dismissed.

Also action listeners are independent of the PopupWindow i.e. if you have a button in content_view then you can set the onClick listener the same way you set it in normal case.

You should set the PopupWindow background, otherwise pressing back button won't dismiss it.

HTH !

Comment: Thank you for your response Karan, but I have not been able to find a way on how to monitor the focus of the PopupWindow, Basically what I want is that if the user clicks on the imageview behind the popup, the popup gets dismissed. Some OnWindowFocusLost callback maybe. Apparently when the popupappears, the other elements of the GUI stop responding e.g. buttons are unclickable etc.

Comment: Other GUI elements (not present in the PopupWindow) won't respond to the click/touch when PopupWindow is visible. Also if you click outside the PopupWindow, then it should dismiss it automatically (if it is not then post the code).

Comment: Thank you very much Karan for your guidance. PopupWindow works very well with my requirement only do I figure out now that Dialogs would have complicated the matters since I would have had to add focus listeners etc. to know when click was done outside. This is what I did to make it respond to the back button:myPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable((Drawable) new ColorDrawable(0)); And I did this to give it the ability to dismiss itself when some other GUI element is clicked: .setOutsideTouchable(true); I just had to delve into the matter more extensively. I do not know how I missed this before.

Comment: Make sure you call setBackgroundDrawable before you show the dialog... otherwise it still wont close on back button press.

Comment: any idea how to handle the background fade with popupWindow?

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be:

1. Make the "dialog" an element of the layout, but initially with android:visibility = "gone". Make sure to put it as the last element in the RelativeLayout so that it is above all the other layout elements (z-ordering).
2. In the onClick method for Button 1, toggle the visibility to "visible".
3. In the OnFocusChangeListener for the view, toggle it back to "gone" in the onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) method whenever hasFocus is false.

EDIT: To make the dialog an element of the layout, you would do something like:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <!-- Your other layout items here -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+dialoglayout"
    android:layout_alignBelow="@id/yourbuttonbarlayout
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <!-- Your dialog elements here -->
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Make sure to give your button bar layout an id (I've assumed yourbuttonbarlayout for the id. If you want three such dialogs, you can give them all the same layout parameters and toggle the individual visibilities. They can all show up in the same spot.

You can always use a background for the layout to simulate borders.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the prompt response. I cannot make the dialog an element of the main.xml file since it 1. Has to be in a seperate window with borders etc. 2. An imageview which is actively being used by the application is at it's back or rather I don't know how to overlay all of that further in a layout already containing the button bar and imageview. 3. For every button i.e. button 1,2,3 there would be a different popup/dialog. It might make the layout too messy. If you think not, I will give it my best shot. What do you mean by make a dialog an element of the layout? Thank you.

Comment: I've upvoted the other answer because I agree that PopupWindow is the way to go, but it seems like you wanted to avoid it, which prompted my answer.

Comment: Brian, Indeed PopupWindows was the way to go. I really appreciate the way you helped me out regarding the dialogs, even if I did not use them, I now have a clear vision to their relevant use. Only after exploring the dialogs and popupwindows side by side was I able to grasp the usage of one over the other. Thank you. Jazak'Allah